# Why is `NSLayoutConstraint.multiplier` read-only?

Tags: ios, macos, autolayout, uikit

What is the rationale behind this decision, why have they done that?

How comes `constant` is read-and-write while, while `multiplier` isn't?

Comment: You're probably much more likely to get a factual answer if you as Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Updating the constant of a constraint can be done very efficiently and
> fast. Changing its multiplier on the other hand is much more
> complicated on the inside and basically produces the same amount of
> work than removing and adding a constraint.
>
> The API reflects this complexity so that developers are aware that
> this is a more expensive operation.

Posted 20 hours ago by Frameworks Engineer https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655663